# Check if it is users first visit

Tags: jquery

Not sure how to do this, but what I was looking to do is run a simple jquery animation such as

```
$(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
          $(this).remove()
        });
```

but only when the user first visits the site. So when the user goes back to the homepage say after visiting a sub page they dont see the animation every time. Can this be done in jquery by creating a cookie and checking it? or something on those lines?

Comment: Yes you can with cookies but understand that cookies can be deleted.  Your best bet would be to have a database with the user.  You can save their ip address in a row.  But then you would have problems if they went to the site on a different computer.

Comment: Using a cookie is a completely valid approach to this.  Users that delete cookies should expect the default behavior of the website after deleting cookies.  Creating server-side scripts and a database is overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to define some simple javascript for "getting", "setting" and "deleting" cookies.  I use the following 3 functions that I just copy and paste to my next project, so explaining what everything is doing is beyond the scope of this answer except that **setCookie** sets a new cookie, **getCookie** retrieves the value of a cookie based on a key, and **delCookie** deletes a given cookie.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){var exdate=new Date();exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;}
function getCookie(c_name){var c_value = document.cookie;var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");if (c_start == -1){c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");}if (c_start == -1){c_value = null;}else{c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);if (c_end == -1){c_end = c_value.length;}c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));}return c_value;}
function delCookie(name){document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';}
```

Next, in your document ready function, you would want to check if a cookie already exists:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Checks if the cookie already exists
    if (!getCookie('firsttime')){
        //Runs the code because the cookie doesn't exist and it's the user's first time
        $(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        }); 
        //Set's the cookie to true so there is a value and the code shouldn't run again.
        setCookie('firsttime',true);
    }
});
```

Now, if you want to reset the code somehow (say for testing purposes to imitate someone's first time), simply open up the console in the developer's pane (Ctrl+Shift+J or F12 in Chrome) and type in the following and press [ENTER]

```
delCookie('firsttime');
```