# Set Laravel 5 cookie so that CSS animation only runs on first visit

Tags: css, cookies, laravel, navbar, laravel-5

I would like to check if it is the users' first visit to my website site by setting a [cookie](http://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies) in [Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/master). If it is, then fade in the navbar (I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) 3.3.1 and [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)). On subsequent visits I want to check for the cookie and if it exists, then show the default navbar with no animation.

Just to be clear, I have got the animation working, it is just the setting and retrieval of the Laravel cookie that I am interested in.

I have got it working how I would like using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370177/check-if-it-is-users-first-visit) however I would like to try to get it working using Laravel.

Is there any benefit / downside to implementing this with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the advantage of doing it with Laravel is mostly that you get a nice syntax that matches the rest of your (server side) code and you have something that usually works out of the box.

A nice place for this functionality would be a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers). View composers are triggered every time a specific view gets rendered. The docs states how you can add a new view composer. Inside the service provider you would have this:

```
public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
{
    $view->composer('the-name-of-your-view-with-the-navbar', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\NavbarComposer');
}
```

And here's what your `NavbarComposer` should look like

```
class NavbarComposer {
    protected $cookie;

    public function __construct(Cookie $cookie){
        $this->cookie = $cookie;
    }

    public function compose(View $view){
        $imNew = !$this->cookie->has('visited');
        if($imNew == true){
            $this->cookie->queue('visited', true, 2628000); // this is the value for 5 years
        }
        $view->with('imNew', $imNew);
    }
}
```

Then in your view you are able to use `$imNew` as a variable

```
@if($imNew)
    {{-- show animation --}}
@endif
```

**Note** This code is not tested. I just wrote it based on my knowledge of Laravel 4 and a few things I read in the Laravel 5 documentation. Also, if it even happens to work, I don't know if this is (still) a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response, I am using Laravel 5 (I know it hasn't been released yet but I wanted to get a running start). I don't believe there is a filters file anymore. Is this the same as Middleware?

Comment: Ouh you should have said that... I'll delete this answer. And maybe come back later

Comment: @Mike In case you didn't get notified by the system, I updated and undeleted my answer...

Comment: I did but it doesn't work. I'm still playing around with it to see what else needs to be done.