# Check if it is user is visiting first time with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a system where, if user lands on a page for the first time nothing should happen, but if same user visit again then that page should not load and instead he should go to a different URL.

```
function session() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") > 0) {
        window.location.href = "www.google.com";
    } else {
        document.cookie = "visited";
    }
}
```

Here is the completed html just to test it's workig

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    1st visit
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function session() {
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") > 0) {
            window.location.href = "www.google.com";
        } else {
            document.cookie = "visited";
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So are you calling the function?????

Comment: If the cookie is equal to "visited", the index of that would equal 0, not be greater than 0.

Comment: Personally though I would suggest using localStorage for this.

Comment: Do note, if user clear cookies, they will hit the page again

Comment: @epascarello sorry i don't know about it. I am not good in Javascript. Could you please suggest what i can do to make it work

Comment: That function is not being called

Comment: @LGSon that's not a problem

Comment: It is though.  A method not called, does nothing.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how can i call this function without using it in body tag so it should work on page load?

Comment: Just add `session();` after the function declaration ... or remove the function statement

Comment: @LGSon After what? Body tag or script?

Comment: After the function itself, within the script tag

Comment: @SahibjotSingh You might want to look at this extensive cookie tutorial: https://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/

Comment: I don't know why this question is down voted. If someone doesn't have proper knowledge and have tried to make something work is that how everybody treats them.

Comment: @LGSon thank you let me try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if it is users first visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370177/check-if-it-is-users-first-visit)

Comment: E.g. like this https://jsfiddle.net/8u9y5msq/

Comment: @SahibjotSingh I think the downvotes are for a perceived lack of effort and/or a perceived lack of searching the web for solutions.

Comment: @LGSon didn't work for me. :( Here is the link -> http://ensoulgroup.com/oldwp/cookies-test.html

Comment: @PeterB I have been searching from last 2 hours and the question you mentioned above was the easiest one to implement for me, but that didn't work so i posted the question. Don't know if that is wrong.

Comment: You may need to re-read the 'duplicate' link, the answer has useful cookie methods that you chose to not use, but they are better than what you are doing. Cookies are not just a bit of text, they have multiple properties combined into a string.

Comment: It calls the function now, next step is to learn dealing with cookies ... check Peter B's link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the [Duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27370319/1220550) that I posted.

I am not posting it as a Code Snippet, because for security reasons Code Snippets can't seem to work with cookies. Instead here is a working **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t7mxzoq/6/)**.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){var exdate=new Date();exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;}

function getCookie(c_name){var c_value = document.cookie;var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");if (c_start == -1){c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");}if (c_start == -1){c_value = null;}else{c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);if (c_end == -1){c_end = c_value.length;}c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));}return c_value;}

checkSession();

function checkSession(){
   var c = getCookie("visited");
   if (c === "yes") {
     alert("Welcome back!");
   } else {
     alert("Welcome new visitor!");
   }
   setCookie("visited", "yes", 365); // expire in 1 year; or use null to never expire
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for giving me the correct answer not just downvoting and running away from the question... Really really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 3):

I'm recommend to use local storage =)

```js
    var first_visit = false;
    checkFirstVisit();
    function checkFirstVisit(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('was_visited')){
            return;
        }
        first_visit = true;
        localStorage.setItem('was_visited', 1);
    }
    console.log(first_visit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this

```js
function userfirstcheck(){
  var usercheck = localStorage.getItem('delete')
  if(usercheck == null){
    alert('hi')
    localStorage.setItem("delete", "userforfirst")
  }
  else if(usercheck != null){
    alert('welcome back')
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="userfirstcheck()">
```