# Modifying a cookie to set its path value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Used the answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305110/16898548 to help me activate a function if someone's visited a page for the first time, but I need it to store the cookie path as / regardless of what page they land on, as I only want them to see the popup it generates once per X amount of time. Currently if they visit example.com/shoes, it will set the path to be shoes/, so if they then visit example.com/bags, it will display the popup again.

Full code (Currently learning PHP + JS so am aware there is probably an easier way to do this whole popup, but would like to get full functionality then I'll look at optimising):

```
<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){var exdate=new Date();exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;}

function getCookie(c_name){var c_value = document.cookie;var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");if (c_start == -1){c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");}if (c_start == -1){c_value = null;}else{c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);if (c_end == -1){c_end = c_value.length;}c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));}return c_value;}

checkSession();

function checkSession(){
   var c = getCookie("visited");
   if (c !== "yes") {

        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            var windowSize = $(window).width();
            if (windowSize >= 0) {
            document.getElementById('discountweb').click(); 
            setTimeout(popupstyle, 500); }
        })

    function popupstyle() {

        var list, index;
            list = document.getElementsByClassName("form-bottom");
            for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
        }

        var list, index;
            list = document.getElementsByClassName("form-item");
            for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].setAttribute('style', 'margin-bottom: 0');
        }
        var list, index;
            list = document.getElementsByName("autoform_12");
            for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].setAttribute('action', 'shoes/');
        }
        var list, index;
            list = document.getElementsByClassName("modal__wrap");
            for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].setAttribute('style', 'padding: 0');
        }
      };
    }
   setCookie("visited", "yes", 14); // expire in 1 year; or use null to never expire
}
    </script>
        <div class="discountweb">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="discountweb" data-modal-url="/_process/ajax_fetch_modal_content?type=discount" >
                    Discount Web
                </button>
    </div>
    <style>
            .discountmob {
                display: none;
            }

            .discountweb {
                display: none;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 819px) {
                .popup-img {
                    display: none !important;
                }
                .popup-main {
                    margin: 0 auto !important;
                    width: 100% !important;
                }
                .popup-main img {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                .popup-main h3 {
                    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
                }
            }

            form[name="autoform_10"] {
                margin: 45px 40px;
            }
    </style>
```

*NOTE* Noticed if they visit the home page first it will store the path value as / and i will have no issues for the rest of the site. Same for if they visit example.com/shoes then visit example.com, they will see the popup on those 2 pages, but then the cookie path value is stored as / and wont display the popup on the rest of the site (which is exactly what i need)

Answer (score 0):

After spending a bit more time playing with the code, this seemed to do the trick for me:

```
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
```

to

```
document.cookie="visited=yes;path=/";
```

*NOTE* Removes the expiry functionality doing this and converts the cookie into a session expiration cookie, which in my case, is completely fine. If anyone has a solution that keeps the functionality of the whole cookie that would be appreciated.